# How to use a captured group in the same regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I wanna a regular expression that exp-b occurs the SAME times as exp-a. Just like "(" and ")".
For example, "x" vs "y", "abxefyg" matches, "abxefyyg" not, and "abxxefyyg" does.

How should I code it in Java?

Any advice will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you better explain what you are trying to do here?  Why does `abxxefyyg` match, while `abxefyyg` does not?

Comment: Regex is not the best tool for the kind of problem you have described. Although the title of your question is possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878948/is-it-possible-to-define-a-pattern-and-reuse-it-to-capture-multiple-groups.

Comment: @Tim I believe he wants a regex that checks if both x and y occur the same number of times in a single string. So `abxxefyyg` matches because x and y both occur twice. `abxefyyg` does not match because x occurs once and y occurs twice.

Comment: regexes are not a good solution here. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses

Comment: Using a simple for loop and counting the number of occurrence of each character and then checking for condition is the best way to solve such problems not regex, IMO

Comment: Does `abexxeyfyg` match?

Comment: *"Just like `(` and `)`"* With parentheses, the order matters too, e.g. `()`, `(())`, and `()()` are all good, while `)(`, `))((`, and `)()(` are all bad. Is that the case too for `xy` pairs? If so, then regex is *really* not the right tool for the job.

Comment: @smac89 `abexxeyfyg` does not match. `y` should be together like `xx`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The SAME occurs. `abxefyyg`, `x` 1, `y` 2.

Comment: @jrook Almost, but not suit Java. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes that you want to assert whether a string has the same length of sequence of two different characters.  Using your sample input, we can first do a regex replacement to remove any characters other than `x` and `y`.  Then, split on `(?<=(.))(?!\1)` to generate a string array with two entries, one for the `x` sequence, and one for the `y` sequence.  Finally, assert that these two strings are the same length.

```
String input = "abxxefyyg";
input = input.replaceAll("[^xy]+", "");
String[] parts = input.split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
if (parts[0].length() == parts[1].length()) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

This prints:

```
[xx, yy]
MATCH
```

Here is an explanation of how the regex works:

```
(?<=(.))   look behind and capture a single character
(?!\1)     look ahead and assert that what follows is NOT the same character
```

So, if we split on `(?<=(.))(?!\1)`, then we would be splitting in between any two characters which are not the same.  After doing the regex replacement on the input `abxxefyyg`, we would be left with `xxyy`.  Splitting using the above pattern generates an array with two terms, `xx` and `yy`.

Comment: Great minds. `(?<=(.))(?!\1)`, how it works? Could you explain more?

Comment: @youngzy Check my updated answer for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's a good solution, if there is no ONE Regex matches.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want.

1. The capture group captures a single character.
2. The `\\1` is a backreference to reference what the capture group matched.

So this replaces all double characters with an empty string.

```java
      String str = "AAabbBCCeeFF--#";
      str = str.replaceAll("(.)\\1", "");
      System.out.println(str);
```

This prints

```
aB#
```

Comment: It's great code, but not I want. Thanks.Could I get the times that the group occurs? For example, `aaBBB`, the capture group `(.)`, for `a` the times is 2, `B` is 3.

Answer (score 1):

> Just like "(" and ")"

Parentheses must be *balanced*, i.e. for every `(` there must be a *following* `)`, and you cannot have a `)` without a matching *preceding* `(`.

Regex cannot do this. Just write a simple loop, and keep track of the nesting depth, e.g.

```
public static boolean isBalanced(String text, char startChar, char endChar) {
    int depth = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        if (c == startChar)
            depth++;
        else if (c == endChar && --depth < 0)
            return false; // endChar without matching startChar
    }
    return (depth == 0); // check startChar without matching endChar
}
```

*Test 1*

```
System.out.println(isBalanced("abxefyg", 'x', 'y'));
System.out.println(isBalanced("abxefyyg", 'x', 'y'));
System.out.println(isBalanced("abxxefyyg", 'x', 'y'));
```

*Test 2*

```
System.out.println(isBalanced("ab(ef)g", '(', ')'));
System.out.println(isBalanced("ab(ef))g", '(', ')'));
System.out.println(isBalanced("ab((ef))g", '(', ')'));
```

*Output from both*

```
true
false
true
```