# Simplify this repeating regex

Tags: regex

I have the following valid regex to match various excel cell/range patterns, of the form `A1`, `A1:Z12`, etc.

[image]

- [`^(?:[A-Za-z]{1,3}\d{0,10})(?::(?:[A-Za-z]{1,3}\d{0,10}))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/nzP6bA/1)

Is there a more compact way to do the second part of the match? Basically, the `: <repeat>` part I was hoping to be able to do it with something like:

- `^ (<main_part> ':'<lookahead, keep if before an A-Z> ){1,2} $`

Any way to do that pattern?

Comment: See [Is it possible to define a pattern and reuse it to capture multiple groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41878948/3832970)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew perfect. I suppose the only downside of that is you have to use a capturing group at the start: `^([A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{1,10})(:(?1))?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way without capture groups or lookarounds, use a word-boundary:

```
^(?:\b:?[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{1,10}){1,2}$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/W0UCMe/1)

The word-boundary can't succeed between the start of the string and a colon nor between a digit and a letter, but it does between a digit and a colon or between the start of the string and a letter.

Obviously, it's also possible to do it like that for the same kind of reasons:

```
^(?:[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{1,10}:?\b){1,2}$
```

*(You win one step more with this one, YAY!)*

---

test cases (first pattern):

1. with `:A2`
   It fails because `\b` fails between the start of the string and a non-word character (the colon).
2. with `A2:`
   It fails because there's no colon at the end of the sub-pattern (that is not repeated in this case).
3. with `A2:A2`
   The pattern succeeds. `\b` succeeds because the first time it is between the start of the string and a letter (a word character), and the second time because it is between a digit (a word character too) and a colon (a non-word character).

Comment: oh that's such a wonderful solution thank you! Could you please explain a bit more on why the colon succeeds in one case but not another? Take, for example `:hi`, `hi:`, and `hi:hi`, how would it be different in those with the `\b` ?

Comment: @David542: `\b` is an assertion that succeeds between a word character (from `\w` ie `[letters+digits+underscore]`) and anything else including the limits of the string. This is the reason why the first time it fails (with a string starting with a colon) and the second time it succeeds only if there's a colon between the digit and the letter.

Comment: @David542: note that, for the second time, it isn't so different than testing if the colon is followed by a letter with a lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

Here would be an example pattern you can use, note that AB:AB is not a valid range as described above so that has been modified as well to `\d{1,10}`:

- [`^(?:[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{1,10}(?::(?=[A-Z]))?){1,2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/xZnUe2/1)

[image]

And a better approach would be to use `?1` to recurse to the first pattern:

- [`^([A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{1,10})(:(?1))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/Fz88CC/1)

Note however with this approach we do need the extraneous capturing group at the beginning for this technique to work.